# How to differenciate sprite parts in one image

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have one image of house and in house there are several parts available but in only one image.
I want to paint all parts like red color for wall and black color for roof. But only one image i have so how it is possible to color different portions in one image??

Can i use cocos2d or anything else for this interesting stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill different colors on different part of image by making different  CGRect sprite on   image to be fill but I am sure that it would not solve your problem as the house image must have different shape to be fill like circular ,triangular or rectangular.And using CGrect will give you filling of rectangular size only.
The best possible solution for this would be using different images as the part of house.There  may be other ways also but they would be complex and problematic so try using more than one images as you can fill each image easily.

Comment: I have another issue can you help me to solve it?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176435/animate-sprite-using-color-in-top-to-bottom-effect